# Did India purchase the Gaganyaan design from Russia?

Tags: russia, isro, roscosmos

[Gaganyaan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaganyaan) is an orbital crew module under development by the Indian Space Research Organisation.  [Sources](http://www.astronautix.com/i/indianmannedspacecraft.html) indicate a design based on the Russian Soyuz:

> As of 2015 the design utilized a Soyuz-shaped reentry capsule with a mass of 3735 kg, a diameter of 3.100 m and height of 2.678 m.

**Does this mean that ISRO actually paid Russia for the design** (like China did with Shenzhou), **or did they merely make their own copy?**

The Wikipedia article does acknowledge Russian help with the life support system, thermal system, and astronaut selection and training.  However, this question is about the overall spacecraft design.

Comment: Seems baseless, we have some details on crew module pressure vessel design etc. (https://redd.it/davfo0) but for more you'd have to look through these tenders we've collated. https://old.reddit.com/r/ISRO/wiki/tenders

Comment: @Ohsin: I do not understand what you mean.  Are you saying that it is a Russian design, or are you saying that it is not?

Comment: I am saying it is unlikely as we have ISRO crew capsule designs to compare and eliminate any similarity with Soyuz as that article suggests. And the 2015 CARE flight article was merely a boilerplate without any pressure vessel.